# Do stored procedures have the ability to delete a file from the OS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

Out of curiosity, does a stored procedures have the ability to delete a file from the OS?

If not I will have to make a windows Batch file that deletes the file and then runs the stored procedure using OSQL.

Comment: EXECUTE xp_cmdshell 'delete *.*'

Comment: ill try out the suggestions over the next week or so and eventually i will choose my favorite answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, with the correct permissions, you could execute xp_cmdshell to issue commands to the OS (or call a batch file, whatever), but it's probably not a good idea. If you do use that method, be very strict about permissions.

Edited for clarity.

Comment: You can issue a "whoami" to determine the user behind the SQL xp_cmdshell (it's more fun than looking it up in the services).  There may be policies to consider too.

Comment: +1 though the last sentence is weird, SQL Server already has access to your OS, as does anyone that has sysadmin rights.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

Option 1 
delete a file using xp_cmdshell

```
xp_cmdshell 'del y:\file.dat'
```

Option 2
delete a file using OLE Automation

```
DECLARE @ResultOP int
DECLARE @OLE_Obj  int

EXEC @ResultOP = sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @OLE_Obj OUTPUT
EXEC @ResultOP = sp_OAMethod @OLE_Obj, 'DeleteFile', NULL, 'y:\file.dat'
EXEC @ResultOP = sp_OADestroy @OLE_Obj
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a CLR stored procedure for this.  That's one of the main reasons for the existence of managed stored procedures, to interact with the OS in a safe manner.