# Get Specific Value from the Specific Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I've got a table like below

```
Table_Name

id   Column_Desc
1    <p><img src="images/abc.png" alt=""/></p>
```

I want to get the this src "imageUrl" from this column
Actually I want to use this src while deleting the data
I want to delete the image from the server,
I need a way how to get this path from the column

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: What kind of content can the column contain?  Will it always be `<p>` tags with an `<img />`?  Or could it contain any kind of HTML?

Comment: Actually this data comes from the HTMLEditor it could have any HTML tag u know.... as user edited its page

Comment: Still not enough information; can there be multiple image tags in a single record?  Are they always in the format `<img src="yourimage.png" ... >`?

Comment: yes, i've designed a page in which user can design its own pages it could have any HTML tag, it can be repeat again n again .............. and i want the imageUrl from every IMage Tag......

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables thanx for your response please develop some logic for me thanx

Comment: and format of image tag is standard...always

Comment: `please develop some logic for me thanx`.  You misunderstand what SO is for; you need to show some effort, including the query you have tried so far.  SO users aren't (normally) just going to give you the code.  Also, `develop some logic for me` sounds like you can't be bothered to do it yourself.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables i don't want a code, i just want a logic and little help .... i've tried myself from google and my own logic but i am stuck thats why i am asking.... bro don't mind please

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables bro please you don't help me....thank you soo much  if you r expert it doesn't mean you can abuse any one... i just want an answer in which i m trying soo much but i can't develop a logic that's why in tension i was said that please develop a logic ........ anyway thanx for your kind reply..

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the image URL from the column using an awkward combination of string functions:

```
select substring(
        html,
        charindex('<img src="',html)+10,
        charindex(
           '"',
           html,
           charindex('<img src="',html) + 10
        ) -
        charindex('<img src="',html) - 10
    )
    from foo;
```

[See a working SQLFiddle example here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46c33/3).

It marks the start at the first occurrence of `<img src="` in the string, and the end at the first `"` following the start.  These are simplifying assumptions, which won't work with every possible input that is valid HTML.  But it should work on reasonable input.

**Update 2: This could be extended with a recursive query to find all URLs:**

*Also updated to handle the case when there is no image url*

```
with all_img_urls as (
   select id,
        cast(null as char(1000)) as url,
        html
    from foo
    where charindex('<img src="',html) > 0
    union all
   select id,
       cast(substring(
        html,
        charindex('<img src="',html)+10,
        charindex(
           '"',
           html,
           charindex('<img src="',html) + 10
        ) -
        charindex('<img src="',html) - 10
    ) as char(1000)) as url,
    cast(substring(
        html,charindex('"',html,charindex('<img src="',html) + 10),1000
    ) as char(1000)) as html
    from all_img_urls
    where charindex('<img src="',html) > 0
)
select id,url from all_img_urls where url is not null;
```

[Updated SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e6f99/7).

It's a bit of a mess, but it works.  The basic idea is to find the first image url, then perform the search again starting after that image url ends.

If you need to do better, you probably should not try to handle this in SQL; instead use a programming language that can parse HTML.

Comment: @user1421736, see the update, which finds all image urls, not just the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after is the following:

```
delete from "Table_Name" where "Column_Desc" like '%images/abc.png%'
```

I think that will give you what you want, although I would check that with

```
select "Column_Desc" from "Table_Name" where "Column_Desc" like '%images/abc.png%'
```

first to make sure it returns ONLY what you want.

Comment: If I'm reading their question correctly, they state `i want to delete the image from the server`.   This doesn't delete any images from the server.  Granted, their question *isn't* the clearest...

Comment: Yeah its only delete from the database
My problem is not to delete from the database 
i just want to get this specific path, and path could be different

Comment: I'm confused, how can you delete an image from the server in SQL if it isn't stored in a database. then we will need to know the programming language no?

Comment: @DanielCasserly - it's not pretty, and it's not recommended, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295247/do-stored-procedures-have-the-ability-to-delete-a-file-from-the-os

Comment: Boss, don't be confused... forget the delete problem ............... just tell me how can i get the imageUrl from column using SQL......... thank you for your quick response help please

Comment: So the second SQL statement couple with some sort of SQL string manipulation. - see the other answer. Sorry can't be more useful I usually use PGSQL

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<String> FetchLinksFromSource(string htmlSource)
    {
    List<String> links = new List<String>();
    string regexImgSrc = @"<img[^>]*?src\s*=\s*[""']?([^'"" >]+?)[ '""][^>]*?>";
    MatchCollection matchesImgSrc = Regex.Matches(htmlSource, regexImgSrc, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
    foreach (Match m in matchesImgSrc)
    {
        string href = m.Groups[1].Value;
        links.Add(href);
    }
    foreach (string s in links)
    {
        string FilePath = Server.MapPath("~/");
        FilePath += s;
        if (File.Exists(FilePath))
       {
           File.Delete(FilePath);
       }
        FilePath = "";
    }
    return links;
}
```

Thanx Alot all of You... i've achieved my target with this logic